# Is there any brachah for putting on a headscarf?

Tags: halacha, blessing, commentaries, head-covering

Is there any Brachah for putting on a טיכל or מטפחת (headscarf) - like when one puts on his tallit or like an act like washing ones hands? Same applies to a כיפה or יארמולקע. And if there are no Brachot for putting on these head-coverings, could someone explain to me why no Brachah is said?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean birkas hamitzvah. Are you assuming there's a mitzvas aseh to cover one's head? Or a mitzvas lo saaseh not to have an uncovered head? If the latter, are you aware of any mitzvas lo saaseh that have a bracha? Maybe indicate what you're assuming is the level of obligation to cover one's head, and where that assumption comes from.

Comment: What is the blessing to put on ones pants...

Comment: @ShoelU'Meishiv "...malbish arumim"

Comment: @Oliver exactly. That precedent in halacha should be noted in the question to buttress the premise

Comment: @ShoelUMeishiv assuming the OP means birkas hashevach and not birkas hamitzvah.

Comment: Oter Yisrael beTifarah

Comment: @rohev I was thaught that the headcovering was a sign of one's yirat shamayim; I.e. a symbol of accepting the Ol Malchut Shamayim; G-ds Rulership, or something like that. What I'm trying to say is that it became quite a religious item. So with blessings for seeing a rainbow, before eatong food, washing one's hands, bathing, putting on a tallit etc I wondered if there was a blessing (prayer) fir putting on one's headcovering.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67223/discussion-on-question-by-levi-is-there-any-brachah-for-putting-on-a-headscarf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why we do not recite a berachah upon covering our heads with a kippah:

The Shulchan Aruch (2:6) seems to imply that the obligation of covering one’s head is only an obligation when reciting a berachah and not when walking around. However, see in Yabia Omer (9:1) who writes at length on this subject and concludes that nowadays it is indeed an obligation to walk around with a proper head covering. In any case, being that it is not an absolute obligation, it does not warrant a separate berachah.

The Shulchan Aruch (46:1) actually states that there is a berachah which is recited for wearing a Kippah, or wrapping our head, and it is the berachah of “Oter Yisrael b’tifarah.” The Bet Yosef explains that even though this berachah was originally meant for people who used to wear a turban or proper head covering, it is customary to nevertheless recite this berachah even for those who only wear a small head covering. He adds, that even according to the opinions that it is strictly speaking permitted to walk without a head covering, it is nevertheless a mitzvah for one who does so.

(With thanks to Rabbi Nacson).

Comment: Yes, and 46(2) says that nowadays these blessings are said in the synagogue and with that we fulfil our obligation. So the blessing has become disconnected from putting on the head-covering.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok Berachot 60b tells it is indeed still connected to headcovering, but as one already says this blessing with the blessings for the process of getting up and getting dressed (Elohai Neshamah) it's not necessary to say it again. Traditionally in ancient times headcovering was a part of the clothing one used to wear, and maybe even used to seperate oneself from the other nations in certain ways. I'm not saying that we have to say a blessing, but that there is a strong connection between headcovering and the phrase: oter Yisrael betifarah.

Comment: Levi - beautifully expressed.

Comment: only answers one of the questions out of the 2 about yarmalkas  (which is strange because a tick means the question has been fully answered), the other question about women head coverings is answered bellow

Comment: @user154 no it answers both questions. Oter Yisraeln beTifara applies to women too. (A check mark doesn't mean fully answered, just that the OP wanted to give it a check mark.)

Comment: @DoubleAA i think unmarried women say the same brocho even though they don't cover there hair (also women who do not to cover their hair when they are married) so even though you are right about general head gear which a person wears to thank Hashem make a brocha Oter yisrael,  The question in my eyes was referring to a specific mitpahat or tichel that only a married woman wears and can be uncomfortable in hot weather and a woman might not make a thanksgiving brocho in such conditions so i said that there is no specific brocho for the mitzva  aspect of covering ones hair

Answer (score 1):

As the question with regards to yarmulkes was very well answered by Levi I am only answering the question with regards to married women covering their hair which is obligated in the Torah as it says in Kesubos 72a:

> ראשה פרוע דאורייתא היא דכתיב: ופרע את ראש האשה ותנא דבי רבי ישמעאל: אזהרה לבנות ישראל שלא יצאו בפרוע ראש
>   - Her hair revealed is prohibited from the Torah as it says with the Sotah that "her hair should be revealed." The house of Rabbi Yishmael teaches, this is a warning for Jewish (married) women not to go out with uncovered hair.

Does one make a Bracha when not breaking Shabbos or not showing any inappropriate parts of the body?
Is their a Bracha for fulfilling any of the 365 *Lo taaseh*s (negative Mitzvos)  or *Lav haba michlal asei* (negative Mitzvos inferred from a positive command) in the Torah?

The answer is no. This is because one is constantly obligated to refrain from doing an Aveira and has not "fulfilled" his obligation while not doing an aveira.
For example: there is no exemption of looking at an immodest woman while refraining from looking at a different immodest woman.

This is written explicitly in the Rashba: שו"ת הרשב"א ח"ג ס' רפג:.

> מברכים רק על מה שבעשיית המצווה נפטר האדם מהחובה במצווה זו.
>   One makes a blessing only on the part of a Mitzva which by doing it one is exempt from fulfilling this particular Mitzva.

Comment: R Moshe Feinstein says it's an Aseh not a Lo Taaseh. You don't have to lose more than a 5th of your money to cover your hair. So no this isn't like Shabbat

Comment: @DoubleAA AA i did not include it in the category of Lo taase i merely said that the same din would apply to not say a bircat hamitzva to all lo taases, for the same reason that it would not apply to  this mitzva of covering the hair which is a Lav haba Michlal asei, because of the ongoing command as stated in the Rashba.